# To columns from two different sheet must be same with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have **Sheet1 Column A** and **Sheet2 Column D**.

If I write anything in **Sheet1 Column A**, then **Sheet2 Column D** must be equal to **Sheet1 Column A** value.

below code is just works on **Sheet2 Cell D4** value.

**How to set it for whole column D?**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rng As Range, r As Range
  Set rng = Intersect(Target, Range("E4:E" & Rows.Count))
  If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each r In rng
      If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then
      Sheet14.Unprotect Password:="432742"
        r.Copy Destination:=Sheets("CLOSING BALANCE").Range("D4")
        Sheet14.Protect Password:="432742", AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
      End If
    Next
  Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `r.Copy Destination:=Sheets("CLOSING BALANCE").Range("D" & r.row)`? Not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: You understand my query very well Mr. @BigBen. And Also solved 99.99% of my problem. But it is not deleted data from **Sheet2 Column D** , When I delete data from **Sheet1 Column A.** Otherwise everything is good. Thank You.

Comment: It would seem that you don't want `If Not IsEmpty(r.Value)` then.

Comment: Thanks Mr. @BigBen it works very well. One Last Help Required. How Can I stop copying Formats and just move the cell values only?

Comment: `Sheets("CLOSING BALANCE").Range("D" & r.row).Value = r.Value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comments in an answer:

1. Copy to the same row number on sheet 2:

```
r.Copy Destination:=Sheets("CLOSING BALANCE").Range("D" & r.row)
```

2. Delete corresponding value on sheet 2 if value is deleted on sheet 1:
   remove the `IsEmpty` check:

```
If Not IsEmpty(r.Value) Then ' remove
    ...
End If ' remove
```

3. Copy only the value:

```
Sheets("CLOSING BALANCE").Range("D" & r.row).Value = r.Value
```